# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Assigning animation triggers via @prop="exp" attributes with an expression is invalid.

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5, cli 1.65.

This line  in post.component.html cause the below error.

google console:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Assigning animation triggers via @prop="exp" attributes with an expression is invalid. Use property bindings (e.g. [@prop]="exp") or use an attribute without a value (e.g. @prop) instead. ("<ul class="list-group">
  <li  [ERROR ->]@ngFor="let post of posts" class="list-group-item"> {‌{ post.title }}</li>
```

This is my post.component.html:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li  @ngFor="let post of posts" class="list-group-item"> {{ post.title }}</li>


</ul>
```

This is my post.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: any[];
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response.json());
      this.posts = response.json();
    }

    )
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated it!!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
<li  *ngFor="let post of posts" class="list-group-item"> {{ post.title }}</li>
```

[Here is the official docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf).

Comment: Thank you!!!  I used "@". Instead I should be using "*". Thank you for telling me what my mistake is